# Nested multiline comments in Dart

Tags: dart, comments

My code contains lots of documentation comments written in the multiline comment syntax like in example

```
/** 
 * This class is used as an example.
 *
 * To ask about multiline comments.
 */
class A {
}

/**
 * Another example class with comment.
 */
class B {
}
```

Sometimes, during debuging/refactoring or experimenting with the code, I want to comment out  some blocks of the code. In this example, I would like to comment out the classes `A` and `B`. Is there a way to do this in a simple way without a need to watch where the documentation comments starts and ends and also without a need to comment each line separately with one line comment syntax `//`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dart (contrary to other C-like syntax languages) natively supports nested multiline comments.

So you can just write

```
/* Commented for debugging purposes!!! Do not forget to uncomment!!!
/** 
 * This class is used as an example.
 *
 * To ask about multiline comments.
 */
class A {
}

/**
 * Another example class with comment.
 */
class B {
}
*/
```

And do not care about some nested comments inside the comment block.